# Percona 5.6 not starting automatically after server reboot on Ubuntu with Virtualmin

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, percona

I've got a new install of Ubuntu 12.04 + Virtualmin.  I've upgraded from the default mysql 5.5 to Percona 5.6.  Everything works except for one problem: when the server reboots, Percona is not automatically started.
If I run "/etc/init.d/mysql start", everything works, so it is not a problem with the mysql/percona configuration, it is just that it does not start automatically.

I know there is a difference that mysql under virtualmin was started with "service mysqld start", but percona only works with init.d, and that is supposed to prevent me from using virtualmin/webmin to start/stop/restart mysql now, but what do I do to at least make it start after reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make mysql start at boot

`sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults`

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, update-rd.d is used to manage unit scripts.